# Best approach to show big amount of "grid" data in Android

Tags: android, listview, gridview, tablelayout

I am building an application for Android (1.5) that, after quering a webservice, shows to the user a big amount of data that should be displayed in a "grid" or "table" style.

I must show a result of about 7 columns and 50 rows (for example a customer list with names, addresses, telephone number, sales amount last year and so).

Obviously, the 7 columns will not fix in the screen and I would like the user would be able to scroll up/down and LEFT/RIGHT (important because of the number of columns) to explore the grid results.

Cell selection level is NOT necessary, as much I would need row selection level.

What is the best approach to get this interface element? `Listview` / `GridView` / `TableLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a grid with rows that are 'expandable' to show the child row containing a subset of the data that you could maybe consider as details.  That way the user can look at data for the rows they are interested in, but ignore the rest.

Comment: That is interesting. The problem is that I dont allways have an "unique" or "primary key" column that could use as "expandable row". The question is: Its possible to have a Grid or table bigger than the screen dimensions in which the user is able to scroll left and right?

Comment: OK - see the android tag now, and I'm afraid I don't have an answer, but I'd say, particularly on a small format screen, the less scrolling you can do the better - this would get on my tits quite quickly.

Answer (score 0):

By the objects you mention it looks like you're talking about .NET. In that case GridView will get your data displaying quickly (least programming) and in the most flexible fashion.

All you have to do is assign your contacts data to the grid view's DataSource member and you're done.

Comment: I forgot to tag the question as Android, now its done, The application is for android phones. I was looking for a similar control avaliable in Android.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Android GUI programming, but the best approach for me would be using landscape orientation, few rows per page (like 5-10) and paging so that GUI will not get slow.

Comment: Even that way, landsace orientation is not enough. The important question is if there is a method to show a table or grid bigger than the screen in Android

Comment: Well yes, but columns have priorities - user should see most of the information at once and most important ones without scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the SlowAdapter, **List13** example in the samples folder.
That might answer your questions.

On my PC the path is
"sdk folder"->android-2.1->samples->ApiDemos->src->com->example->android->apis->view

Answer (score 0):

This 2 dimensional scrollview might be what you're looking for: http://androiddevblog.blogspot.com/2009/12/creating-two-dimensions-scroll-view.html

It is using a TableLayout so for reallly large datasets it might not be optimal because the views won't get re-used on scrolling. But 7x50 does'